# Copy file using systemctl

Tags: python, embedded-linux, systemctl

I create python script for embedded-linux, the script monitor USB storage insertion and removal, and if an USB drive insert then the computer copy a file to the USB drive. The script need to be started after boot so I create   service in my system ctl here is myscript.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script Service
After=multi-user.target
[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python2 /home/kiki/PycharmProjects/copyfiletousb  /copyfile.py
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

here is my python file  (copyfile.py)

```
from  __future__ import division
import pyudev
import serial
import time
from shutil import copyfile
import os.path
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
ser.baudrate=19200
ser.write(bytearray(chr(27)))
ser.write(bytearray("                Standby"))
def copyfile(source, dest, buffer_size=1024 * 1024):
    if os.path.exists(dest):
        print "File %s already exists" % dest
        return

    if not os.path.exists(source):
        print "File %s doesnt exist" % source
        return

    if not hasattr(source, 'read'):
        source = open(source, 'rb')
    if not hasattr(dest, 'write'):
        dest = open(dest, 'wb')

    print "Start copy..."
    size=os.path.getsize('fedora.iso')
    size=size//buffer_size
    q=0
    old_propgress=0
    while 1:
        q=q+1
        copy_buffer = source.read(buffer_size)
        progress=((q*100.0)//size)

        if old_propgress != progress :
         ser.write(bytearray(chr(27)))
         ser.write(bytearray(" Copying         file :   \       "+str(int(progress))+" %"))
    old_propgress=progress

        if (progress==100):
            ser.write(bytearray(chr(27)))
            ser.write(bytearray("                  Done"))
        if copy_buffer:
            try:
              dest.write(copy_buffer)
            except:
              ser.write(bytearray(chr(27)))
              ser.write(bytearray("   Ruang        Tidak          Cukup"))
             break
        else:
            break
    print (q)
    source.close()
    dest.close()
    print "Finished!"


context = pyudev.Context()
monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
monitor.filter_by(subsystem='usb')
insert=0
remove=0
for device in iter(monitor.poll, None):


    if device.action == 'add' and insert==0:
        ser.write(bytearray(chr(27)))
        ser.write(bytearray("                USB Terh        ubung"))
        time.sleep(5)
        copyfile("fedora.iso", "/media/kiki/USBSTORAGENAME/vessel.iso")
        insert=1
        remove=0
        print(device.sequence_number)




    if device.action== 'remove' and remove==0:
        insert = 0
        remove = 1
        ser.write(bytearray(chr(27)))
        ser.write(bytearray('                USB terp        utus'))
        time.sleep(2)
        ser.write(bytearray(chr(27)))
        ser.write(bytearray('                standby'))
```

My problem is the data is not transfered to USB storage

Comment: And ... what is your problem ?

Comment: sorry i forget to mention i have edit the question

Comment: So what does `journalctl -e myscript` contain? Any exceptions? Debug messages? Does your script work when you run it in the console directly?

Comment: My script works when I i type : python copyfile.py

Comment: journalctl -e contains nothing